# Moving Eight Nodes Across the Screen (At Random Starting Positions/Intervals)?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I’ve created 8 paddles in `gamescene.sks`. I know how to control them manually but in this case, I want them all to begin automatically oscillating back and forth in their respective ‘lanes’ (meaning they won’t collide with one another) once a button is pressed (I haven’t created the button because idk if that should come before or the paddles function correctly).

I’m not asking for code but I just need a general idea of the commands that I need to implement in order to move a single paddle (positioned randomly) back and forth linearly when a button is pressed. I’m sure I can figure everything else out from there.

Thanks in Advance!!!

START button pressed → 8 paddles (placed randomly in their respective lanes) begin oscillating back and forth (out of sync with one another)

```
import SpriteKit    
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var squareRight = SKSpriteNode()
    var squareLeft = SKSpriteNode()

    var paddleL1 = SKSpriteNode()
    var paddleL2 = SKSpriteNode()
    var paddleL3 = SKSpriteNode()
    var paddleL4 = SKSpriteNode()

    var paddleR1 = SKSpriteNode()
    var paddleR2 = SKSpriteNode()
    var paddleR3 = SKSpriteNode()
    var paddleR4 = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        squareRight = self.childNode(withName: "squareRight") as! SKSpriteNode
        squareLeft = self.childNode(withName: "squareLeft") as! SKSpriteNode

        paddleL1 = self.childNode(withName: "paddleL1") as! SKSpriteNode
        paddleL2 = self.childNode(withName: "paddleL2") as! SKSpriteNode
        paddleL3 = self.childNode(withName: "paddleL3") as! SKSpriteNode
        paddleL4 = self.childNode(withName: "paddleL4") as! SKSpriteNode

        paddleR1 = self.childNode(withName: "paddleR1") as! SKSpriteNode
        paddleR2 = self.childNode(withName: "paddleR2") as! SKSpriteNode
        paddleR3 = self.childNode(withName: "paddleR3") as! SKSpriteNode
        paddleR4 = self.childNode(withName: "paddleR4") as! SKSpriteNode        
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered       
    }    
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between "control them manually" and what you're asking about?

Answer (score 1):

As a general set of guidelines, I would:

1. Create a `PaddleDirection` enum with values of stationary,
   movingRight and movingLeft
2. Subclass SKSpriteNode to create a `PaddleNode`
3. Add a property `var currentDirection = PaddleDirection.stationary` to  your PaddleNode.
4. Make sure all your paddles are PaddleNodes and not SKSpriteNodes
5. When the start button is pressed, enumerate through all the
   PaddleNodes and set their currentDirection properties to movingRight (or left, or randomly select one or the other)
6. In `update()` enumerate over all the paddles and adjust their
   position according to whether they are moving left or right.
7. When each paddle reaches the limit of its movement, change its
   direction from left to right or vice-versa.

Comment: you cant add stored properties to an extension

Comment: Oh yeah - forgot about that. Subclassing it is then.

Comment: yeah if we could do that.. that would be sweet ;)

Comment: actually, you could use the `userData` for the direction.. but it wouldn't work with the enum without parsing

Comment: @Fluidity You could, but I always fell that using a subclass is clearer, even if you are only adding a single property.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a [Strategy Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), if you want to put a name to it!